# Creating a regex to match html attributes

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I know that there are a lot of answers to vim/regex, but I can't seem to find one that fits the bill for me. So, I'm trying to remove some attributes from HTML using the following:

```
%s/( id="\| onfocus="\| onBlur="\| style="\| title=") [a-zA-Z0-9:;&$_\.\s\(\)\-\,]*"//gc
```

I'd like to be able to replace any of the specified attributes and everything up to and included the second `=`.

When I run this, I get `pattern not found`. However, if I take the parens off of `id="\| onfocus="\| onBlur="\| style="\| title="` I get a match for `id=` and I get a match for everything on `title="hi"` How can I include all of the attributes in one regex?

**Edit:** A result of running

```
%s/ id="\| onfocus="\| onBlur="\| style="\| title=" [a-zA-Z0-9:;&$_\.\s\(\)\-\,]*"//gc
```

will change

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" title="submit" value="submit" />
```

To

```
<input type="submit" submit" value="submit" />
```

You can see it picks up the `id=` but not the text and double quote after the attribute up to the next space. However, it is pattern matching the correct thing for the `title` attribute. In this example `title="submit"` has been fully removed.

Comment: it is always better to provide some few real original lines of text and example of the resulting lines expected. Could you edit the question and add this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
 %s/\(id\|class\)="\([^"]*\)"/\2/gc
```

1. You catch `id` and `class` in the first group to add the **big fat or** `\|` operator.
2. You match `="`
3. You catch the text you want to keep in the second capture group `\([^"]*\)` (assuming here you want anything up to a `"`).
4. You match the closing `"`
5. And you leave only the second group.

You can then use `\2` as you want.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it leads directly to what I was asking. I left out the `\2` because I'd like the entire selection to be removed. However, thanks for the tip for future reference!